# Nginx HTTPS redirect loop with multiple domains

Tags: nginx, redirect, lets-encrypt, 301-redirect

I know that there are other questions with similar topics, but I can't find a solution anywhere that solves my specific problem. The difference here is multiple domains with different sites.

I have Nginx set up with multiple domains: `example1.com` and `example2.com`. There's also the "default" host files that have the ["Welcome to Nginx!" default web page](https://www.nginx.com/blog/welcome-to-nginx-on-my-favourite-website/).

I've tried a few different configurations including:

```
# 1
server {
   server_name example2.com www.example2.com;
   listen 80;
   return 301 https://example2.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name example2.com www.example2.com;
    listen 443 default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

---

```
# 2
server {
    server_name example2.com www.example2.com;
    listen 80;
    listen 443

    return 301 https://example2.com$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}
```

`1` results in:

- **http**://example**2**.com redirecting to **https**://example**2**.com showing the "Welcome" page
- **http**://example**1**.com redirecting to **https**://example**2**.com showing the "Welcome" page
- **https**://example**1**.com showing the actual content of example**1**.com

`2` results in:

- **http**://example**2**.com with a redirect loop
- **https**://example**2**.com with a redirect loop
- **http**://example**1**.com redirecting to **http**://example**2**.com with a redirect loop
- **https**://example**1**.com showing the actual content of example**1**.com

I can't put the content for `example2.com` in the default "Welcome" folder or it would affect `example1.com`.

Comment: The results you are getting are consistent with the configurations you have shown. Option (1) has no `root` directive and will therefore point `https://example2.com` to the `nginx` default page, and option (2) redirects to itself.

Comment: What is the behavior that you actually want?

Comment: What I’m hoping for is http:// example2.com > https:// example2.com and http:// example1.com > https:// example1.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Richard Smith, I know know how I messed it up. I hadn't included the root locations correctly. Here's the correct files in case it can help someone else:

```
# example2.com.conf:
server {
    server_name example2.com www.example2.com;
    listen      80;
    return      301 https://example2.com$request_uri;
    # What I was missing:
    root            /var/www/example2-com;
}
server {
    server_name     example2.com www.example2.com;
    listen      443 ssl;# default_server;

    # What I was missing:
    root            /var/www/example2-com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/privkey.pem;
    include         /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam     /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}

# example1.com.conf:
server {
    server_name example1.com www.example1.com;
    listen      80;
    return      301 https://example1.com$request_uri;

    # What I was missing:
    root            /var/www/example1-com;
}
server {
    server_name     nerd.ink www.nerd.ink;
    listen      443 ssl; # default_server;

    # What I was missing:
    root            /var/www/example1-com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem;
    include         /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam     /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```